PyTorch move nn.module to cuda including submodules and wrapper modules
I would like to move my module to Cuda.
There is a code example:
class SubModel(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(SubModel, self).__init__()
        self.conv1 = nn.Conv1d(in_channels=1, out_channels=1, kernel_size=2)

    def forward(self, x):
        print(f"x type:{type(x)}")
        print(f"weight type:{type(self.conv1.weight)}")
        return self.conv1(x)

class WrapperModel(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, count):
        super(WrapperModel, self).__init__()
        self.blocks = []
        for i in range(count):
            self.blocks.append(SubModel())

    def forward(self, x):
        for block in self.blocks:
            x = block(x)
        return x
     
class MyModel(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MyModel, self).__init__()
        self.conv = nn.Conv1d(in_channels=1, out_channels=1, kernel_size=2)
        self.wrapper = WrapperModel(2)
        

    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.conv(x)
        x = self.wrapper(x)
        
        return x


However, I encountered a runtime error when executing self.conv1(x) in the forward function in SubModel:
RuntimeError: Input type (torch.cuda.FloatTensor) and weight type (torch.FloatTensor) should be the same
The output of the print commands are:
x type:<class 'torch.Tensor'>
weight type:<class 'torch.nn.parameter.Parameter'>

Then I tried to move the wrapper to the Cuda at the end:
model.wrapper.to(device)

It didn't fix it.
Finally, I move the conv1D in the subModel to the cuda:
class SubModel(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(SubModel, self).__init__()
        self.conv1 = nn.Conv1d(in_channels=1, out_channels=1, kernel_size=2).to(torch.device('cuda' if torch.cuda.is_available() else 'cpu'))


It works fine! However, the print output did not changed:
x type:<class 'torch.Tensor'>
weight type:<class 'torch.nn.parameter.Parameter'>

Therefore, I have no idea what's wrong going here.
I also feel that it's too inconvenient that I have to manually move all instances to the Cuda.
**My question: is there a convenient method to move a model to the Cuda including all the subModels within it? **

I have figured it out. I should use ModuleList to hold the instances of SubModel in WrapperModel instead using a normal list.
self.blocks = nn.ModuleList([SubModel() for _ in range(count)])

